# Как сохранить созданный DropDownItems?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть menuStrip1 и в нём есть две вкладки Save и Load. При нажатии на Save у меня появляется форма с textbox, я ввожу туда текст и нажимаю на кнопку. После этого у меня в Load появляется DropDownItems с его именем введённым в textbox. Вопрос как сохранить созданный DropDownItems? Что бы он появился после повторного включения программы.

Comment: DropDownItems возвращает [ToolStripItemCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection) в которой есть коллекция элементов Item. Сохраняйте ее любым удобным способом.

Comment: @ГеннадийП вот он и спрашивает любой способ))))

Comment: Используй сериализацию. Бинарную или в XML или в JSON

Answer (score 0):

Сохранение:

```
var collection = toolStrip.Items;
var list = collection.Cast<ToolStripItem>().Select(s => s.Text);
File.WriteAllLines("list.txt", list);
```

Загрузка:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("list.txt");
toolStrip.Items.AddRange(lines.Select(s => new ToolStripButton(s)).ToArray());
```